# ./configure doesn't generate MAKEFILE when building x11spice

Tags: make, configure, makefile, spice

I am trying to enable [x11spice](https://github.com/jwhite66/x11spice) in my Docker container, I followed the README but after `./configure`, there is no MAKEFILE was generate, so `make` has an error output saying `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Here is the output of `./configure`:

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal 
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Autoheader
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --no-force
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
./configure: line 2692: syntax error near unexpected token `XCB,'
./configure: line 2692: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(XCB, xcb)'
```

And here is what are in the directory after that, there are two different file containing Makefile called Makefile.ac and Makefile.in

```
AUTHORS  ChangeLog  Makefile.am  NEWS    aclocal.m4  autom4te.cache  config.log  configure.ac  doc
missing  test-driver COPYING  INSTALL    Makefile.in  README  autogen.sh  compile         configure   depcomp       install-sh  src
```

The `x11spice` repository hasn't been updated for nearly a year, so I don't count on them to fix it. Is there anyone who has tried this or similar ones that can solve this issue? I'd be appreciative!

Comment: Unless you feel you can debug the code / make file you will need to contact the author or the source code.

Comment: It seems that I have to file an issue on the GitHub repository then. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours attempt, I managed to fixed this issue. The problem is actually not about syntax error with `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`, it's about a step prior to `./configure`. Check back to `README` in [x11spice](https://github.com/jwhite66/x11spice) repository. We need to run `./autogen.sh` first. While doing so, multiple errors indicating package requirements were not met appears. One of the examples is like:

```
checking for XCB... no
configure: error: Package requirements (xcb) were not met:

No package 'xcb' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables XCB_CFLAGS
and XCB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

What we need to do is simple:

1. use `apt-cache search xcb` to find what package need to be installed to satisfy this package requirements.
2. Then use `apt-get install` to install it/them.
3. Run `./autogen.sh` again to see if there is other issue remains. If so, go through step 1 and 2 until `./autogen.sh` has an output saying:

   ```
   configure: creating ./config.status
   config.status: creating Makefile
   config.status: creating src/Makefile
   config.status: creating src/tests/Makefile
   config.status: executing depfiles commands
   ```

That's when you go to run `./configure`. Hope you will fix your problems following these instruction.